# Weird behavior of Python's built-in max() method

Tags: python, python-3.x

While using Python's `max()` built-in method I've found an interesting thing....

```
input_one = u'A測試測試;B測試;測試;D測試測試測試;E測試測試測試測試測試測試測試測試測試'
input_two = u'測試測試;測試;測試;測試測試測試;測試測試測試測試測試測試測試測試測試'
input_en = u'test;test,test,test;testtesttest;testtesttesttest'
input_ja = u'ああああああ;あああ;あああああああ;ああああああああああああ'
input_ja_mixed = u'aああああああ;bあああ;cあああああああ;dああああああああああああ'
input_ascii = u'egfwergreger;@#@$fgdfdfdfdsfsdfsdf;sdfsdfsfsdfs233'


def test_length(input):
    lengths = []
    for i in input:
        lengths.append(len(i))
    index = find_index(input, max(lengths))
    return input[index]


def find_index(input, to_find):
    for index, value in enumerate(input):
        print('index: %s, length: %s, value: %s' % (index, len(value), value))
        if len(value) == to_find:
            return index

def test_one(input):
    input = input.split(';')
    print('input:', input)
    print('using test_length: ', test_length(input))
    print('using max():', max(input))
```

If using `max()` to find the max element in a list which only contains English alphabets, it works good.

But, if the element is mixed with symbols(like `@` `#` `$`), it behaves differently.

For example,

```
In [80]: test_one(input_ascii)
input: ['egfwergreger', '@#@$fgdfdfdfdsfsdfsdf', 'sdfsdfsfsdfs233']
index: 0, length: 12, value: egfwergreger
index: 1, length: 21, value: @#@$fgdfdfdfdsfsdfsdf
using test_length:  @#@$fgdfdfdfdsfsdfsdf
using max(): sdfsdfsfsdfs233
```

The special case is, Chinese mixed with English alphabets:

```
In [82]: test_one(input_one)
input: ['A測試測試', 'B測試', '測試', 'D測試測試測試', 'E測試測試測試測試測試測試測試測試測試']
index: 0, length: 5, value: A測試測試
index: 1, length: 3, value: B測試
index: 2, length: 2, value: 測試
index: 3, length: 7, value: D測試測試測試
index: 4, length: 19, value: E測試測試測試測試測試測試測試測試測試
using test_length:  E測試測試測試測試測試測試測試測試測試
using max(): 測試
```

The documentation doesn't specify any special behavior the `max()` method has.

Python version is Python 3.4.

Is this my problem or it's something that behaviors I don't know about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your `test_length()` function does not do the same thing that `max()` does, `max()` , when the given inputs are strings, returns the lexicographically largest element from the input , not the one with the largest length.

A simple example to show this -

```
>>> a = 'aaaaaaaaaa'
>>> b = 'b'
>>> max(a,b)
'b'
```

Your `test_length()` function works based on the length of the string, which is different from what `max()` does.

`max()` also supports a `key` argument to which you can pass a function object, which will be used to determine which is the maximum element in the input. In your case you can pass in `len` to make `max()` work on the lengths of the string, Example -

```
>>> a = 'aaaaaaaaaa'
>>> b = 'b'
>>> max(a,b,key=len)
'aaaaaaaaaa'
```

Comment: I see. Went re-read the docstring. Finds out that I skipped a couple line:(

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
>>> max(['aaa','b','cc'])
'cc'
```

vs:

```
>>> max(['aaa','b','cc'], key=len)
'aaa'
```

If you want the 'max' to use the length of the string vs the ascii code of the first character of the string, use a key function -- in this case with the built-in `len` function.